# Runtime Error 4605 Excel VBA Copying multiple ranges to word document

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently writing a macro to copy and paste multiple non contiguous ranges to a Word document. It all works perfectly, almost everytime. The problem is that sometimes I get a runtime error 4605 when using the macro. I already tried a few things: `DoEvents, "application.cutcopymode = false", EmptyClipboard()` function I found, adding wait time with `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`
Nothing really worked, some of them fixed it more than others, for example the "application.cutcopymode = false" made it so that the error was pretty rare, but it still happened.
Now for the code:

```
For intCounter = 2 To 27
        If intCounter > 2 Then wdApp.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

'------------------------------------------------------------
        Set rng1 = Worksheets(intCounter).Range("E2:G3")
            rng1.Copy
        On Error Resume Next
        wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False

'------------------------------------------------------------
        Set rng2 = Worksheets(intCounter).Range("E6:G7")
            rng2.Copy
        On Error Resume Next
        wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
 Next intCounter
```

I know it's ugly to use the copy command after every range declaration, but if i didn't do that there would be an error that they have to be contiguous.
Is there a way to fix this error or do I have to scrap this idea and do maybe a temp excel sheet and then copy it from there?

Thanks
M.S

Comment: @M-schedl: you might find some ideas at [help with VBA and clipboard run time error 4605](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/933965-help-vba-clipboard-run-time-error-4605-a.html)

Comment: I check out both of those links before making this thread, but I didn't try @Steven suggestion in the stackoverflow thread and that seems to have fixed it. Sry for making this post. Should I delete it?

Comment: @M-Schedl: well, it's already closed as a duplicate, so deleting it is really up to you